# Parsing time zone with SimpleDateFormat.java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How do i parse a timezone out of "US/Mountain", "US/Pacific", ...etc using SimpleDateFormat?

The following code throws a ParseException

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyyy hh:mm a zzzz";
String value = "7/18/2016 05:00 PM US/Mountain";
new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(value);
```

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

I should be able to use 'z' (or multiple z's) to get a timezone out of text but I'm not sure what list of strings or patterns SimpleDateFormat.java is looking at.

I understand that I could use different Java library or even do this myself for a limited set of timezones and strings (ugh).

But my question is really about the **proper use or SimpleDateFormat** to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the `z` refer to the "display name" of the time zone.

You can try to use the `TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain")` then get its display name by using method `getDisplayName()`

probably something like this would suffice.

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain");
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyyy hh:mm a zzzz";
String value = "7/18/2016 05:00 PM " + tz.getDisplayName();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(value));
```

Comment: It looks like TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain") returns "Mountain Standard Time" is there no way to parse "US/Mountain" using SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @Ervin not so sure. But by cursory read the source code. It seems it is only possible if the zone id is not known. But, the code itself does use the display name as the value though for the formatting. So, I guess you should stick with the display name.

Answer (score -1):

Posting my comment as an answer:
I believe you have one redundant 'a' in your pattern ))